# Check whether file has been opened already

Tags: file, fortran

I am writing a file reading library, and need to check whether a file has been opened so that I can skip the open statement and go directly to a read.

How can this be achieved in fortran?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When one wants to know about connections to external files there is the `inquire` statement.  There are two forms to this: inquire by file; inquire by unit.

[tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31941769) shows inquire by unit.  This tests whether unit 3 is connected to *any* file.  One could then go on to ask the name of the connected file with the `name=` and `named=` specifiers.<sup>1</sup>

Inquire by file allows one to ask: is a given file connected to *any* unit, and if so, to which unit?

```
inquire(file=filename, number=unit)
```

If the file is not connected then `unit` will be `-1`, otherwise `unit` will correspond to the unit connected to the file.

Alternatively, depending on what you want to do with the `open` statement, it isn't necessarily erroneous to `open` with an already connected file.

---

<sup>[1] The variable in the `name=` specifier will become undefined if the file has no name.  Testing this variable against the desired filename when it is undefined is bad.  The `named=` specifier allows detection of this case.</sup>

Comment: Great, the topo is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `inquire`:

```
logical itsopen 
inquire(unit=3, opened=itsopen) 
if ( itsopen ) then
    write(*,*) 'Its open already'
else
    open(3,'myfile.txt')
end if
```