# to have an array containing units or names of the already opened files in fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran

Is there any way to have an array (returned by a `fortran` intrinsic  subroutine) containing units or names of the files that are already opened by a `fortran` program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to include your test code.  The answer is _yes_.

Comment: I can obtain the units or names of the already open files through a do loop, but I'd like to get them as an array returned by a generic subroutine.

Comment: Do you want an intrinsic subroutine? If so there isn't - you will have to write your own routine

Comment: There is no intrinsic subroutine to do this. Further, any user-written subroutine will have to face the challenge of preconnection. In light of that challenge, it may help if you can further describe exactly what requirements you have.

Comment: File and unit [inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31941681/3157076) may be part of the solution

Answer (score -1):

Yes here is an example of putting unit numbers into an array.

```
      PROGRAM LUN_ARRAY_TEST
      INTEGER N
      PARAMETER(N=10)
      INTEGER LUNS(N)      
      INTEGER I
      CALL OPEN_FILES(N,LUNS)
      DO I=1,N
        WRITE(6,*) "LUN ",I," = ",LUNS(I)
      ENDDO
      CALL WRITE_LINES(N,LUNS)
      CALL CLOSE_FILES(N,LUNS)
      END

      SUBROUTINE OPEN_FILES(N,LUNS)
      INTEGER N
      INTEGER LUNS(N)
      INTEGER I, LUN
      CHARACTER*80 FILENAME
      DO I=1,N
        LUN=60+I
        WRITE(FILENAME,100) I
 100    FORMAT('FILE',I3.3)
        OPEN(UNIT=LUN,FILE=FILENAME,ACTION='WRITE')
        LUNS(I)=LUN
      ENDDO
      END

      SUBROUTINE WRITE_LINES(N,LUNS)
      INTEGER N
      INTEGER LUNS(N)
      INTEGER I
      DO I=1,N
        WRITE(LUNS(I),*) I
      ENDDO
      END

      SUBROUTINE CLOSE_FILES(N,LUNS)
      INTEGER N
      INTEGER LUNS(N)
      INTEGER I
      DO I=1,N
        CLOSE(LUNS(I))
      ENDDO
      END
```

Comment: thanks, In your code you know what files are open now, because you have opened them yourself. This is not my case.

In my situation, I don't know how many files with what names and unit numbers are open now. So i need a subroutine that tells me for example there are N files with these names and unit numbers which are open now.